# selector 'nix-repl' matches no derivations

Tags: nix

I have nix installed

```
➜  which nix
/Users/rabraham/.nix-profile/bin/nix
➜ nix --version
nix (Nix) 2.1.3
```

Nix Channel is:

```
➜ cat ~/.nix-channels
https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09 nixpkgs
```

But I can't install `nix-repl`

```
➜ nix-env -i nix-repl
error: selector 'nix-repl' matches no derivations
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation is outdated. I think `nix repl` already works without a separate install from Nix 2.0 onwards.